# How to get Bootstrap modal to work with form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to close a modal with Bootstrap.  But I'm getting an error that "modal is not a function" when I run my script.  I think it has to do with context.  Here is my code.  Note that the call to "modal hide" works outside the submit listener.  I have to use this listener because the form is in a modal and otherwise the script has no idea where "register-form" is since it's in a different view for the modal.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('submit', '#register-form',  function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       jQuery('.bs-modal').modal('hide');

       data = jQuery('#register-form').serialize();
       jQuery.post('/campus-learning/registration-form', { data: data }, function() {

       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to alias jQuery to get it to work.  Hope this helps someone else.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery(document).on('submit', '#register-form',  function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       $('.bs-modal').modal('hide');

       data = jQuery('#register-form').serialize();
       jQuery.post('/campus-learning/registration-form', { data: data }, function() {

       });
    });
});
```